# Matlab Parpool fl::except On linux - not enough inodes

Tags: linux, matlab, parallel-processing, inode, parfor

**Edit 2/5/17:** After some work with our system deparment, it seems that this happens when Linux is low on inodes. My question is, therefore, why are the two related, and how could I have known it from the error message?

**Problem Details:**

I run Matlab R2016b on Linux (CentOS 6.3), and for the past couple of days I keep getting a non-familiar error when I try to do open parallel threads. Specifically, writing

```
parpool(3);
```

yields as always

```
>>starting parallel pool (parpool) using the local profile ....
```

But then, after a short while, I get

```
>> Caught unexpected fl::except::IInternalException
```

and it crashes. (The double 'I' in Internal is intentional).

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm: If you start 'clean' and run `parpool(3)` this error always occurs? Without exexution of any other code? And how about using parpool(1) or 2, or 10? -- Shot in the dark: Any chance that your local profile changed, whatever impact that may have?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - (a) Yes, even if I start clean and do `parpool(1)` it behaves the same. (b) As for the shot in the Dark - I'm not sure I understand all the terms, or their consequences.

Comment: I'd recommend making a Mathworks support request if you haven't yet.